# Is the developable surface between two conic sections, not in the same plane, algebraic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider two conic sections located in non-parallel planes in $\mathfrak{R}^3$ and parameterized as $\mathbf{P}_1(t)$ and $\mathbf{P}_2(t)$. Consider the ruled surface: $\mathbf{R}(s,t)=(1-s)\mathbf{P}_1(t)+s\mathbf{P}_2(t)$ that "interpolates" the two curves. Are there always reparameterizations of $\mathbf{P}_1(t)$ and $\mathbf{P}_2(t)$ such that the ruled surface $\mathbf{R}(s,t)$ becomes a developable surface? In addition, are there corresponding rational parameterizations of the conic sections for this (if it exists) developable surface? Finally, and independently, is such a surface algebraic?

Comment: Consider the graph of the function $f(x,y)=e^x$. Your question is more appropriate for math stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks. The question was not right. I reformulated. I might go over to stack exchange instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that such convex hull will be always 3-dimensional. If you mean the boundary of this convex hull, then it will never be developable. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think an asker, especially a new user, deserves more chances to clarify their question than that.

Comment: @Jap88 Is a cylinder, viewed as the convex hull of two circles in two planes, an example of what you mean? Then I guess you want to take the boundary of the convex hull, less any components contained in the planes. Such a set will always be semialgebraic, at least - defined by polynomial equations and inequalities. One proof of this is to use the quantifier elimination for real closed fields, but that's a bit of a sledgehammer.

Comment: @WillSawin thanks. I understand the comment by MoisheKohan. It wasn't clear. I have tried to clarify.  Convex hull was not the correct term here.

Comment: You might look at this paper: Ranestad, Kristian, and Bernd Sturmfels. "On the convex hull of a space curve."  [arXiv:0912.2986](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2986) (2009). "The edge surface is in general the tangent developable of a curve." "The union of all
stationary bisecant lines is the *edge surface* of the curve."

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thanks. I have read some of Sturmfels work before. So, a question then is if a tangent developable of this kind is always algebraic? I will read the article.

Comment: This was a question related to a stack-exchange question. For some applied algebraic geometry and a partial answer to this question, see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3974536/cylinder-between-two-circles-in-mathbbr3/3977171#3977171